# Create customer in QuickBooks offline

Tags: quickbooks

I have created a sample .NET web app that connects to QuickBooks Online and using pages/forms in the app I can create/update customer records in QB. I would like to know how customer records in my database can be migrated to QB Online so that user does not have to explicitly logon to QB online. I read about WebConnector but it works with desktop version of QB. So I need to have ability to be able to create/update records in QB Online (using a background process) whenever customer records are added or updated in my SQL Server database without connecting to QB Online.

I am thinking of writing a WCF windows service that will call QBOnline API to do this work periodically but not sure how I will connect that service to QB Online. Please suggest if QB supports this (and how) or I have to force users to logon to QB to create/update customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to know how customer records in my database can be migrated to QB Online so that user does not have to explicitly logon to QB online.

The *very first time* you establish a connection to QuickBooks Online, the *user must login*.

That only needs to be done ONCE. After that very first time, you should be storing your OAuth tokens, and you can send data over anytime you want without any user interaction what-so-ever.

If that's not the behavior you're seeing, it's probably because you're not storing the OAuth tokens like you should be.

> I read about WebConnector but it works with desktop version of QB.

Do not use the Web Connector. If you've already implemented a sample .NET web app that connects to QuickBooks Online, then you're on the right path.

> I am thinking of writing a WCF windows service that will call QBOnline API

Why would you do this? This is making things so much harder than they have to be... you already implemented a sample .NET web app, keep doing what you're doing.

> Please suggest if QB supports this (and how)

It does.

You already implemented a sample app, which means you've already done what you're asking to do. Just make sure you're storing the OAuth tokens so you don't have to keep reconnecting all the time. The connection process by the user should happen ONLY ONCE. If it's happening more than once, you're not storing the tokens like you should be.

Comment: Thank you, Keith for your quick reply. I have few questions more.

Comment: @user1787231  If you have more questions you need to either post a new question, edit your question, or comment here. DO NOT edit my post to ask YOUR questions.

Comment: Ok, I will post new question in the comment. Here it is.. I do not want this web application to be a SaaS application and do not want to go for tech, security, marketing reviews. I want to open it only for my client. In my developer account I see next stages like tech, security, marketing review stages. Intuit documentation says that developers can privately distribute applications and so need not go through the reviews. If it is so, why do I see the stages mentioned above ? Do I still need to go through these reviews ?

Comment: If you do a private publish, you don't need to go through tech/security/marketing. When you choose to publish, you'll be given the option to publish to AppCenter or not. Make sure you choose NOT to publish to AppCenter, and then none of those things are required.